# Installing pynput results in ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1

Tags: python, pip, pynput, termux

Im trying install pynput by using `pip install pynput` and output like this

```
    $ pip install pynput
Collecting pynput
  Using cached pynput-1.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (99 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-xlib>=0.17 in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pynput) (0.31)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pynput) (1.16.0)
Collecting evdev>=1.3
  Using cached evdev-1.4.0.tar.gz (26 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for evdev, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: evdev, pynput
    Running setup.py install for evdev ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-a4x3o5ji/evdev_c26c21c2fb7741e49333f8636dfc1cb0/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-a4x3o5ji/evdev_c26c21c2fb7741e49333f8636dfc1cb0/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-record-56ud8l4q/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/python3.9/evdev
         cwd: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-a4x3o5ji/evdev_c26c21c2fb7741e49333f8636dfc1cb0/
    Complete output (37 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/evdev
    copying evdev/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/evdev
    copying evdev/device.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/evdev
    copying evdev/ecodes.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/evdev
    copying evdev/eventio.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/evdev
    copying evdev/eventio_async.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/evdev
    copying evdev/events.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/evdev
    copying evdev/evtest.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/evdev
    copying evdev/ff.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/evdev
    copying evdev/genecodes.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/evdev
    copying evdev/uinput.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/evdev
    copying evdev/util.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.9/evdev
    running build_ext
    running build_ecodes
    The 'linux/input.h' and 'linux/input-event-codes.h' include files
    are missing. You will have to install the kernel header files in
    order to continue:

        yum install kernel-headers-$(uname -r)
        apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
        emerge sys-kernel/linux-headers
        pacman -S kernel-headers

    In case they are installed in a non-standard location, you may use
    the '--evdev-headers' option to specify one or more colon-separated
    paths. For example:

        python setup.py \
          build \
          build_ecodes --evdev-headers path/input.h:path/input-event-codes.h \
          build_ext --include-dirs  path/ \
          install
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-a4x3o5ji/evdev_c26c21c2fb7741e49333f8636dfc1cb0/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-a4x3o5ji/evdev_c26c21c2fb7741e49333f8636dfc1cb0/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-record-56ud8l4q/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/python3.9/evdev Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: [Linux, OSX and w32](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/limitations.html) are the only supported platforms. I doubt it could work on Android even in Termux.

Comment: There's [x11-repo](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Graphical_Environment) in Termux. I successfully installed `pynput` & `evdev` on Termux, but I'm not sure if they'll work, still testing. To install `evdev`, you have to specify where your linux kernel headers (`input.h`, `input-event-codes.h`) are when running `setup.py`, as specified in [evdev doc](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#specifying-header-locations). To do so, first look up kernel version by `uname -a`. Then download & extract kernel code from [kernel.org](https://kernel.org).

Comment: `evdev` works on my Android device. I'm able to read & write touch screen events. I'm not using graphical environment on Termux, so I'm not going to test `pynput`. I guess it'll work, too.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message installing evdev for a different package; what fixed it was installing the prerequisites.  From the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/python-evdev.1.html#from%20source) (I quote debian but pick your distribution):

> The  latest  stable  version of python-evdev can be installed from
> pypi, provided that you have gcc/clang, pip and the Python and Linux
> development headers installed on your system.  Installing  them  is
> distribution  specific  and  typically falls in one of the following
> categories:
>
> ```
>    On a Debian compatible OS:
>
>       $ apt-get install python-dev python-pip gcc
>       $ apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by installing a lower version:

```bash
pip install pynput==1.6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

1. View kernel version by `uname -a`, `uname -r` or something else.

```
$ uname -r
4.4.153-perf+
```

2. Download & extract kernel source from [kernel.org](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/).

```
$ wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.4.153.tar.gz
$ tar -xf linux-4.4.153.tar.gz
```

3. Download & extract [evdev source](https://pypi.org/project/evdev/#files).

```
$ wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/ec/bb298d36ed67abd94293253e3e52bdf16732153b887bf08b8d6f269eacef/evdev-1.4.0.tar.gz
$ tar -xf evdev-1.4.0.tar.gz && cd evdev-1.4.0
```

4. Build and install `evdev`.

```
python setup.py build \
    build_ecodes --evdev-headers /data/data/com.termux/files/home/linux-4.4.153/include/uapi/linux/input.h:/data/data/com.termux/files/home/linux-4.4.153/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h:/data/data/com.termux/files/home/linux-4.4.153/include/uapi/linux/uinput.h \
    build_ext install
```

5. `pip install pynput`

This works on my device. I'm able to read & write touch screen events using `evdev`.